# Why does using an & in data or class = formula fields interfere with wb_add_data in OPENXLSX2

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I'm attempting to write a small table of formulas to an excel sheet. It works perfectly except if I try to use "&" characters. Here's my code:

First I add a worksheet called Summary, build a dataframe that I'll populate with formulas and add it to the workbook.

```
if(exists("df_tmp")) {rm(df_tmp)}
a <- c("Above and Beyond", "Fully Met", "Partially Met", "Did Not Meet") # try using "&" instead of  "and"
b <- c(.15, .70, .10, .05);
c <- c("","","","")
d <- c("","","","")
e <- c("","","","")
f <- c("","","","")
df_tmp <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)

## Add Formula(s): Summary Table ----
wb <- wb_workbook()
wb$add_worksheet("Summary")

df_tmp$c = paste0('F',seq(4,7),'/SUM($F$4:$F$7)')
df_tmp$d = paste0('ROUNDDOWN((COUNTA(Population!A:A)-1)*C',seq(4,7),',0)')
df_tmp[1,5] = paste0('COUNTIF(Population!G:G,"Above and Beyond")') # try using "&" instead of "and"
df_tmp[2,5] = paste0('COUNTIF(Population!G:G,"Fully Met")')
df_tmp[3,5] = paste0('COUNTIF(Population!G:G,"Partially Met")')
df_tmp[4,5] = paste0('COUNTIF(Population!G:G,"Did Not Meet")')
df_tmp$f = paste0('E',seq(4,7),'-F',seq(4,7))

class(df_tmp$c) <- c(class(df_tmp$c), "formula")
class(df_tmp$d) <- c(class(df_tmp$d), "formula")
class(df_tmp$e) <- c(class(df_tmp$e), "formula")
class(df_tmp$f) <- c(class(df_tmp$f), "formula")

colnames(df_tmp) <- c("Rating","Target Percentage","Actual Percentage", "Target Count", "Actual Count", "Δ to Meet Distribution Targets")
wb <- wb %>% wb_add_data(sheet = "Summary", df_tmp, dims = wb_dims(3, 2))
if (interactive()) wb$open()
```

This code works perfectly. However, if I replace the "and" with an "&" in the strings indicated above, the workbook errors. I've tried escaping it with "\" but no matter what I try, I get this error when attempting to open the workbook:

[image]

Any thoughts? The ampersand & is an unfortunate requirement for me as these workbooks process input data over which I have no control. Hopefully I'm skipping something obvious. Thank you for your wisdom!

Comment: David please post issues on GitHub. It looks like this needs escaping. ‘&’ is a special character in xml and you have to write ‘&amp;’ instead

Comment: You have to use `df_tmp[1,5] = paste0('COUNTIF(Population!G:G,"Above &amp; Beyond")')` atm, because we do not escape the formula when it's passed as class variable as we shoud

Comment: First, thank you. I had tried that as you suggest above, using &amp; instead - however, in Excel, the result is that "Above &amp; Beyond" is printed in the cell rather than simply "&".

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/JanMarvin/0d4e567bd8a1c6f612abe765b02e966b) should work. Tested with MS365 (includes only the line from above and an additional worksheet). I've added two pull requests to solve the issue so that no `&amp;` is required anymore. In the formula part we unescape xml so that `a &amp; b` is always interpreted as `a & b`. In usual data we don't. Therefore your `a &amp; b` is escaped as `a &amp;amp; b`. I don't want to add the gist as answer, because future people should not have to bother with xml escaping at all.